# Conditional Probability about succeeding in nth attempt given the failure in n-1 attempts

Tags: probability

You bought a new computer game and based on your previous experience, you know that the probability of suceeding at the game is only 20% [P(S) = 0.2]. Assuming that this probability is constant:
Show that the probability of not succeeding is P(U) =0.8
i. Given that you didn't succeed the first time, find the probability that you succeed the second time.

ii. Given that you didn't succeed in first two attempts, find the probability that you succeed in the third attempt.

iii. Given that you didn't succeed in the first (n-1) attempts, find the probability that you succeed in the nth attempt.

iv. What is the relationship between the event S and U that lead to the results above?

Solution:
I have tried solving it using conditional probability:

Event U is not succeeding and event S is succeeding. So given that You do not succeed in 1st attempt but succeed in 2nd attempt
the resultant probability will be conditional
P(succeeding in 2nd | not succeeding in 1st) or  P(S2|U1)= P(S2 and U1) / P(U1)
= P(S2) x P(U1) / P(U1)
= 0.2 × 0.8 / 0.8 
= 0.2

part ii

P(S3|U2) = P(S2 and U2) / P(U2)
= 0.2 x 0.8 / 0.8
= 0.2

iii)
P(Sn|Un-1) = P(Sn and Un-1) / P(Un-1)
=0.2x0.8/0.8
=0.2

iv) So we find out that given that previous attempt was not succesful, probability of next attempt remains the same, i.e., 0.2
This is because the 2 events S and U are independent.

Comment: You should write about your thoughts and attempt to solve the question.

Comment: What is the event U?

Comment: Event U is not succeeding and event S is succeeding. So given that You do not succeed in 1st attempt but succeed in 2nd attempt P(S2|U1)= P(S2 and U1) / P(U1) = 0.2 × 0.8 / 0.8 = 0.2 Is this correct way to solve part i?   If this is correct how would I apply conditional probability for part ii P(S3|U2) = P(S2 and U2) / P(U2) ???

Comment: These events are independent so in each case the probability of winning is 0.2 regardless of previous results.

Comment: Got it. but why the above uses conditional probability whereas we will use multiplication rule to find the probability if the question is changed to "If you do not succeed in the 1st attempt and succeed in the 2nd attempt" Whats the difference?p

Comment: No, that would be "what is the probability of not succeeding on the first but succeeding on the second". The only logic I can see in a question like this under the heading of conditional probability is so you can clearly see the difference between independent and dependent events.

Comment: Why use conditional probability unless the player learns something each time so the probability of success improves?

Comment: If it is not solved by conditional probability, how else can this be solved?